# Can I manually create EF Core's PropertyValues for use in tests?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF Core has a [`PropertyValues`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/PropertyValues.cs) type, which holds current/old values from the database.

In my tests, I often need an object of this type, and the only way to get it is to write to the db and then get an instance from the context.

So I want to manually create an instance. But it's abstract (and seems to complicated to implement) and all related classes are internal and abstract (and too complicated to implement).

Can this be done? Maybe there's some helper type that can help, which I don't know of.

Comment: What I'm trying to do right now is `var values = CreatePropertyValues(entity);` which will populate the internal list of property values with the values in the entity. Some methods would throw, but that's fine, as all I need is get the code under test to be able to call its `GetValue<>()` method. I've also tried to mock it (using NSubstitute), but it isn't straightforward.

Comment: Maybe you can use EF Core InMemory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: @H.Herzl I am using InMemory, but for a large number of tests, the process I've described above is nonetheless slow and ugly. So I still want to manually create PropertyValues.